# How do I change the names of rows in ANOVA output table for r markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I need to change the rows of my ANOVA output. I have already figured out how to change the columns. I'm icelandic, so this may be confusing to read.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
options(scipen=999)
library(broom)

fervik_medalfermverd <- aov(fermetraverd ~ matssvaedi, data = urtak2)

kable(anova(fervik_medalfermverd),  col.names = c("Frígráður", "Fervikasumma", "Meðalfervikassumma", "F-gildi", "P-gildi"))
```

How do I change the rows?

Comment: Could you add some data, making your example works? It's useful to use `dput(your_data)` and post the result if you can publish them, in other hands you can create some fake data and post them, to copy and past in R. This is good practice to post reproducible code to detect your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convert the anova object to a data frame/tibble and try something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
options(scipen=999)
library(broom)
data(mpg)

tmp <- aov(cty ~ displ, data = mpg)

df <-
  anova(tmp) %>% 
  as_tibble()

colnames(df) <- c("Frígráður", "Fervikasumma", "Meðalfervikassumma", "F-gildi", "P-gildi")
rownames(df) <- c("Label 1", "Label 2")

df %>% 
  kable()
```

This gives:

```
|        | Frígráður| Fervikasumma| Meðalfervikassumma|  F-gildi| P-gildi|
|:-------|---------:|------------:|------------------:|--------:|-------:|
|Label 1 |         1|     2691.064|        2691.063754| 408.2482|       0|
|Label 2 |       232|     1529.282|           6.591735|       NA|      NA|
```